# Haskell: Making packages available for a new GHC installation

Tags: haskell

If I have GHC installed in /opt/ghc and all the Haskell libraries in /opt/haskell (--global), how would I go about GHC upgrades?

All I need to do to upgrade GHC is remove its directory and untar a new one.
How do I make this new GHC installation aware about all the packages in /opt/haskell?
Do I have to recompile all the packages with the new GHC?  Is there a bulk register command or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Packages compiled with one GHC aren't compatible with packages compiled with another; the ABI isn't stable, and upgrading to a new major version of GHC practically guarantees that previously-compiled libraries won't work. You'll have to recompile your packages when you upgrade GHC, I'm afraid.

See this GHC FAQ entry: [*Do I have to recompile all my code if I upgrade GHC?*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/FAQ#Do_I_have_to_recompile_all_my_code_if_I_upgrade_GHC.3F)

Comment: Thanks. Shame though ... :( Very inconvenient if you have tons of packages residing in ~/.cabal or in some global location. At least, is there a convenient way to bulk recompile all available packages with the new compiler?

Comment: `cabal install --reinstall world` should do it.